# While defending my castle, does garrison or my own party spawn first?

Tags: mount-and-blade

My garrison list puts a bunch of archers at the top, which is fine.  But I'm also going to need a bunch of infantry at the beginning, since the Khanate outnumbers me 10 to 1.  I need to hold the wall from the very beginning.

So, if I put a bunch of Huscurls at the top of my party list, will they spawn first?  Or does my garrison spawn first?  Or do soldiers spawn from both lists simultaneously?

Comment: I can't really remember since it has been a while, but I think both spawn. That the garrison is a different group all together, so your top of your party will spawn, and also the top of your garrisson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will spawn from both lists simultaneously.

When you are in the castle, its is guaranteed that you will spawn, but not guaranteed that your party will completely spawn with you unless the total number of forces you have is less than the maximum allowed for your side during the battle.

If you have more than that amount, then a scattering of your forces will spawn along with a portion of the garrison.  Good luck holding the castle, the khergit lancers are surprisingly good at castle seiges due to their 2 handed polearms, watch out for them especially.

Comment: All true. My castle was taken very quickly, so I reloaded the saved game a few times and tried different troop orders.  Both lists did spawn simultaneously, although not 50/50. It seemed to spawn slightly more of the garrison.

Comment: @AndrewNordFace was your garrison forces larger than your party?  I think it spawns in the same ratio of army size.